# Reactjs: How can i change the language of my react project on select options

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, chakra-ui

I had completed the design and now I want to add the functionality to change the language of my project on select options.

[image]

Comment: check out this package [react-intl](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-intl)

Comment: The question is how can i implement ?

Comment: refer to docs ..